# HDBSCAN cluster: still unclear to me how to chose 'min_cluster_size`

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering

Hdbscan is an excellent technique to find the "optimal" number of clusters within your data when you have little a priori idea how many clusters should exist. This makes the method great for exploratory analysis:

http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html

Here's my problem: All results using hdbscan with the python implement in the link above rely on the crucial min_cluster_size

http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter_selection.html

If users have a priori little idea how many clusters best fit the data, what is the correct approach above? Isn't there a metric one uses to decide what the optimal number of clusters is?

Answer (score 2):

Optimal in which sense?

The crucial thing with clustering is that there is no optimal solution. Different solutions tell you a different part of the story. And to be able to get different views, you will **need parameters**. It is a exploratory technique.

Various attempts at defining "optimal" solutions have failed for practical use, just think of k-means.

Comment: By "optimal", I mean certain clusters fit the data better than others.

Comment: Define "fit the data". `min_cluster_size=1` supposedly is the "best fit" yet subjectively usually much worse. There exists no objective notion of "best" that people find useful...

Comment: So what's the point of clustering?

Comment: Tool to give you ideas how to *look* at your data. Nothing automatic, too unreliable.

Comment: We're off the beaten track, but after getting a set of clusters...what am I supposed to infer with these? Investigate the properties of clusters? The consequences of the techniques are slightly strange

Comment: Yes. study the data. This is exploration.